# grep complaining `grep: : No such file or directory`

Tags: bash, grep

Have written the following test for a script.

I call it in the following way, to get the `grep` complaint.

```
test --FS="," --incl=.texi,.org -C 8 --dyn="package" ./01cuneus
grep: : No such file or directory
```

I found out that `fdir` contains an empty element, which might be the reason for the problem.

```
test ()
{

  local fs=""  fdir=()  incl=()
  local dyn=0  ctx=0  fdir=""
  local isufx=()  ictx=()
 
  shrtopts="C:"
  longopts="FS:,incl:,dyn:,dynamic:,context:"
  
  opts=$(getopt -o "$shrtopts" -l "$longopts" -n "${0##*/}" -- "$@")

  eval "set -- ${opts}"
  while (( $# > 0 )); do
    case "$1" in
      # ----------------------------------------------
      ("--FS")
        fs="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
      ("--incl")
        incl+=("$2") ; shift 2 ;;
      # ----------------------------------------------
      ("--dyn"|"--dynamic")
        dyn=1 ; ptrn="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
      ("-C"|"--context")
        ctx=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
      # ----------------------------------------------
      ("--")
        shift ; break ;;
      # ----------------------------------------------
    esac
  done

  if (( $# >= 1 )); then
    
    declare -A tag                # declare Associative Array
    for dpa in "$@"; do
      [[ ! -d $dpa ]] && continue  # skip to next iteration
      [[ ${tag[din:$dpa]} ]] && continue
      fdir+=("$dpa")
      tag[din:$dpa]=1
    done

  fi

  [[ ! -z "$ctx" ]] && ctx=8
  ictx=( -C "$ctx" )

  (( ${#incl[@]} == 0 )) && incl=( .texi .org )
  
  if (( ${#incl[@]} > 0 )); then

    for ext in "${incl[@]}"; do
      s="$ext"
      [[ (! -z "$fs") && ("$ext" == *"$fs"*) ]] && s=${ext//"$fs"/" "}
      for fltyp in $s; do
        isufx+=( --include="*$fltyp" )
      done
    done
    
  fi
    
  grep -rl "${isufx[@]}" "$ptrn" "${fdir[@]}" |
    while read f; do
      echo -e $(tput setaf 46)"==> $f <==\n"$(tput sgr0)
      grep -ni "${ictx[@]}" "$ptrn" "$f"
      echo ""
    done

}
```

Comment: I am using an array constructed as `"${isufx[@]}"` which gives `--include=*.texi --include=*.org`.

Comment: From what *exact* command did you get `grep: : No such file or directory`? If I'm reading the question right, some *undisclosed command* gave you the error and *some other command* you actually posted "does not show the problem". Now we know the other command but *not the troublesome one*. Please [edit] and provide information as close to [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659) as possible.

Comment: The error can be replicated by `grep foo ''`. Check your relevant arrays/variables for *empty* elements. How exactly did you create the arrays?

Comment: Use `set -x` to see the command that goes to `grep`, there's an empty filename there. Then use something like `declare -p fdir isufx ictx` to see what the variables really contain. Judging from the extra space in `fdir:  ./01cuneus`,   there's probably an empty element at the start of the `fdir` array, but you're not showing how it's initialized, just the `fdir+=("$dpa")` appending to it. Also you're not showing how you call the script, or what command you use to print the contents of the variables. POST COMPLETE SCRIPTS! Don't demand the people who could help you to guess what your code does.

Comment: I have identified an empty value in `fdir`.  For the array, I am getting `[Key: 0, Value:], [Key: 1' Value: ./01cuneus]`.

Comment: I initialise `fdir` with `local fdir=()`.  I call the script using `region --dyn="short" ./01cuneus`.

Comment: Note that we generally don't do interactive debugging sessions here.  You have made substantial edits to the question in response to comments.  This leads me to believe that it will be most difficult to pin down the question for long enough to be able to give a single consistent answer to it.

Comment: ok, again: please post **COMPLETE** (but _minimal_ scripts)! **We don't have your code, we don't know how it works, we don't know what's in the parts you left out**. But we do know those parts can well have something to do with what happens, esp. because shell scripts often have loads of global variables.

Comment: And if the full script is too large to post, then _make it_ minimal. Remove the unnecessary parts. Restructure the script until it's small enough, but still shows the problem. Throw out the argument processing for the arguments you don't use. *But keep it complete and functional.* And if it just so happens, that while you doing that, the problem goes away, then you know the problem is in the part you just changed. So look there. You'll probably find the cause yourself, and faster. (Also with less yelling.)

Comment: Yes, people will complain with the full script.  I have made a test.

Comment: @Pietru, yep, that looks more like a complete and verifiable piece of code. Now, if you'd posted that right away, you'd have gotten your answer faster.

Comment: Thank you @ilkkachu for your demand on posting a complete script.  There was no chance to identify the problem otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `test` function, you have two lines at the start saying

```bsh
  local fs=""  fdir=()  incl=()
  local dyn=0  ctx=0  fdir=""
```

Notice how you assign an empty string to the `fdir` variable?

Later, you *append* data to `fdir`, using it as an array.  This leaves an empty element at the start of the `fdir` array, which is giving you the issue that you describe.

Don't initialize `fdir` to an empty string.

Comment: Problem solved ! I just did not see that.  It was basically a remnant of an old version, that remained there through the new versions.

Comment: Also related is the fact that [Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing with a subscript of 0](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#:~:text=Referencing%20an%20array%20variable%20without%20a%20subscript%20is%20equivalent%20to%20referencing%20with%20a%20subscript%20of%200)